# How can I construct RAW request from an HAR (HTTP Archive) file?

Tags: http, archive, har

Since a request can have postData and the different mimeType behave differently,
What is the best way to reconstruct the RAW Request from HAR format.

Note: I'm using C#, but any solution\tip regardless of the programming language would be great.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, you could use an external library such as [HarSharp](https://github.com/giacomelli/HarSharp).

Taking the examples from the github page:

**Deserialize from string:**

```csharp
var har = HarConvert.Deserialize(harContent);
```

Where `harContent` is a string from your HTTP Archive file.

**Deserialize from file**

```csharp
var har = HarConvert.DeserializeFromFile(fileName);
```

Where `fileName` is the path to your HTTP Archive file.

I'm personally looking at this library but I wish to do the reverse - generate a HAR file from the HttpContext. But I can't see anything to do that.